# Grid in Python Tkinter is Resizing Without Reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid, character-replacement

I am creating a To - Do List In Python, and I have to arrange 3 elements as I start. These include a Notebook in order to flip through notes and to - dos. The others are just labels with images on them. Here is the code. My question is that I'm not sure how I am supposed to go about putting these images on the grid. The Notebook, which is located Row 1, Column 0, is very large and causes the column 2 to shift all the way right, which gets rid of the ability to put two items in two columns close to each other in row 1. Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()
root.title("To - Do List")
root.geometry("1200x600")
root.configure(background = "white")
# Variable list:

content = ttk.Frame(root)
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))


Photo1= PhotoImage(file="Full Circle Image Icon Docs.png")


Photo2 = PhotoImage(file="To - Do List Label.png")


TasksList = ttk.Notebook()
Task1 = ttk.Frame(TasksList)
Task2 = ttk.Frame(TasksList)
TasksList.add(Task1, text = 'One')
TasksList.add(Task2, text = 'Two')
TasksList.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

Label(image=Photo1, bg="black", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(image=Photo2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
root.mainloop()
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the grid three columns wide and then set column weigth=1 to the third column to let it expand with the window. Then place the labels in column one and two.

Then let the TasksList fill all three columns with: `columnspan=3`.

Also I put the TasksList in the second row and let it have weight=1 to expand with the window. See this example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x600+800+50")
# Set which cols and rows should expand with window
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

TasksList = ttk.Notebook(root)
Task1 = ttk.Frame(TasksList)
Task2 = ttk.Frame(TasksList)
TasksList.add(Task1, text = 'One One One One One One')
TasksList.add(Task2, text = 'Two Two Two Two Two Two')
TasksList.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+W, columnspan=3)
# Make the TaskList span all three columns ------^

Photo1= PhotoImage(file="test.gif")
Photo2 = PhotoImage(file="test.gif")
# Put labels in root
Label(root, image=Photo1, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, image=Photo2, bd=0).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
# Don't put anything in column=2

root.mainloop()
```

In row=0 the third column (empty) will expand to fill the window. In row=1 the TasksList will expand to fill the window. See [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it was of use to you.